# G4GDMLParser Evaluator : syntax error C++

Tags: c++, file, simulation, geant4

I am trying to read a GDML file with G4GDMLParser:

```
...
G4GDMLParser parser;    
parser.Read(G4Str_Filename, fValidate);
```

But it gives an error:

```
  ...
    G4GDML: Reading materials...
    G4GDML: Reading solids...
    Evaluator : syntax error
    
    -------- EEEE ------- G4Exception-START -------- EEEE -------
    *** G4Exception : InvalidExpression
          issued by : G4GDMLEvaluator::Evaluate()
    Error in expression: 40.0
    *** Fatal Exception *** core dump ***
     **** Track information is not available at this moment
     **** Step information is not available at this moment
    
    -------- EEEE -------- G4Exception-END --------- EEEE -------
    
    
    *** G4Exception: Aborting execution ***
    Signal: SIGABRT (Aborted)
```

I tried putting GDML file next to the executable but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

I found it problem is My locale TR uses " , "not " . " for floats just set your locale somewhere in your code;

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US.UTF-8");
```